# Android AWS APIGateway Authentication HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, httpurlconnection, amazon-cognito, aws-api-gateway

Having an issue using Cognito and API Gateway to access our REST API's

I can't for the life of me find a simple example of how to call a secured REST api on our AWS server.

I call

```
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                    ProfileViewActivity.this, // get the context for the current activity
                    AMAZON_COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID, // your identity pool id
                    Regions.US_EAST_1  //Region
            );
```

and then try to make a call to our server which is a part of that POOL.  I keep getting back "Forbidden".

What should I do with credentialsProvider in the headers of the HttpURLConnection ?

UPDATED:

Ok using the APIGateWay the right way with the AWS Generated SDK however unsure how to change the generated file:

```
    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private TextView textView;

    public MyAsyncTask() {
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        AWSCredentialsProvider credenetialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                ProfileViewActivity.this,          // activity context
                AMAZON_COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID, // Cognito identity pool id
                Regions.US_EAST_1 // region of Cognito identity pool
        );

        ApiClientFactory factory = new ApiClientFactory()
                .credentialsProvider(credenetialsProvider)
                .region("us-east-1")
                .endpoint("https://myendpoint")
                .apiKey("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");


        // MyClient is the AWS Android SDK Generated class

            final MyClient client = factory.build(MyClient.class);

         client.feedGet();

        String str  = client.testGet().toString();


        Log.d("###", "here after test" +client.testGet().toString());


        return "DONE";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String temp) {
        Log.d("####", "onPostExecute");
    }
}
```

and then

```
    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private TextView textView;

    public MyAsyncTask() {
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        AWSCredentialsProvider credenetialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                ProfileViewActivity.this,          // activity context
                AMAZON_COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID, // Cognito identity pool id
                Regions.US_EAST_1 // region of Cognito identity pool
        );

        ApiClientFactory factory = new ApiClientFactory()
                .credentialsProvider(credenetialsProvider)
                .region("us-east-1")
                .endpoint("https://myendpoint")
                .apiKey("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");


        // MyClient is the AWS Android SDK Generated class

            final MyClient client = factory.build(MyClient.class);

         client.feedGet();

        String str  = client.testGet().toString();


        Log.d("###", "here after test" +client.testGet().toString());


        return "DONE";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String temp) {
        Log.d("####", "onPostExecute");
    }
}
```

========= MyClient.java  - AWS Android SDK Generated File

```
    @com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.annotation.Service(endpoint = https:myaws_server)
public interface MyClient {
    @com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.annotation.Operation(path = \"/test\", method = "GET")
    Empty testGet();
```

Comment: Are you using the generated Android API Gateway SDK? In that case you should be able to instantiate a new API Gateway client using the credentials provider from Cognito and those requests should work. It might help if you shared the code where you are using the API Gateway client.

Comment: I've updated the question with the code I'm using  - changed to API Gateway but its not failing with a proxy error

Comment: Hello. Did you get any success? i am also facing the same issue

Comment: Hey @Krishnavrinsoft, I finally went back to the APIGateway and did it that way.  Once I was able to see the JSON that was passed back I was able to update the ASK generated code and getting values back.  Let me know if you want to go this route and I'll provide a tutorial.  The AWS guys told me they were going to update the docs so we will see.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeah please I need tutorial. I am facing issues still 2 weeks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using  AWS API Gateway, you can use it independently without using AWS Cognito. AWS API Gateway is a http service just like a proxy to your server or a Gateway to your AWS Lambda Function.

[aws api gateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/welcome.html)

Comment: Thanks @cenxui-lin, however when I tried that I'm getting "Cannot evaluate $Proxy1.toString() and have no idea what that means.

Comment: Cognito is the way to directly use AWS service without API Gateway ,I guess you are wrong to use Cognito  to access API Gateway, If I was worng,correct me.

Comment: Hey @cenxui, I don't think you're wrong, I just can't get to the url to use the Cognito authentication.